# XML::Simple not grabbing individual XML nodes

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, mediawiki-api

I'm using the MediaWiki API to get search results. I simply want to grab the URL to the first result, the XML element marked 'Url'. There will eventually be other things I will want to do with the XML, but I suppose in getting an answer for this I will realize what I'm doing wrong and be able to do the other stuff. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=rooney&limit=10&namespace=0&format=xml)'s the page I'm working with.

```
require HTTP::Request;
require LWP::UserAgent;
require XML::Simple;

my $url = URI->new("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=rooney&limit=10&namespace=0&format=xml");
my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->request($request);

my $xml = XML::Simple->new(); 
my $data = $xml->XMLin($response->content);
```

Everything up to here seems to work fine. My HTTP request goes through alright (if I just print `$response->content` it returns the XML content fine and if I print `$data`, I am told that it is a hash.

In attempt to get the 'Url' element, I have tried numerous approaches based on the searching I've done. A few below:

```
print $data->{'Url'};
print $data->{Url};
print $data{Url}
```

Comment: The `XML::Simple` module established its namespace by being first in line, and I am sad that new programmers are still choosing to use it just because of its label. Its author has put a lot of work into improving it, but it still fails to differentiate properly between elements and attributes, and won't consistently retain the order of elements within an XML document. It mishandles processing instructions, entities, namespaces, CDATA, PCDATA, comments, and a lot more. Please use `XML::Simple` *only* if your XML data is trivial and know what you are doing.

Comment: I suppose I don't always know what I'm doing, especially with Perl. Can you suggest the best alternative?

Comment: XML::LibXML, XML::Twig or XML::Rules are popular choices these days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pro tip: use `Data::Dumper` to look inside your data structure.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($data);
```

You'll get something like this ...

```
$VAR1 = {
  'xmlns' => 'http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2',
  'Section' => {
    'Item' => [
      {
        'Url' => {
          'content' => 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooney',
          'xml:space' => 'preserve'
        },
        'Description' => {
          'content' => 'Rooney may refer to:',
          'xml:space' => 'preserve'
        },
        'Text' => {
          'content' => 'Rooney',
          'xml:space' => 'preserve'
        }
      },
... much much more ...
```

from which you can deduce that the route to your desired data is through

```
$data->{Section}{Item}[0]{Url}{content}
```

You should also look into using something like [`XML::XPath`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Xml%3a%3aXPath), which makes it much easier to conduct this kind of search.

Comment: I apologize for the previous comment - I must have done something wrong and it is working now. Thanks! `Data::Dumper` will be useful as well.